# How to Implement Paystack payment gateway in react Native

Tags: react-native

Techies... Please, I am new to mobile development using React Native. I have a project I have wanted to implement Pay stack. I install its `npm` and I read about the document... The moment I copy the code into my environment, it was throwing error.

```
`import React, { useRef } from 'react';`
`import  { Paystack , paystackProps}  from 'react-native-paystack-webview';`
`import { View, TouchableOpacity,Text } from 'react-native';`

`function Pay(){`
  `const paystackWebViewRef = useRef<paystackProps.PayStackRef>();` 

  `return (`
    `<View style={{flex: 1}}>`
     ` <Paystack`
        `paystackKey="your-public-key-here"`
       ` billingEmail="paystackwebview@something.com"`
        `amount={'25000.00'}`
        `onCancel={(e) => {`
         ` // handle response here`
       ` }}`
        `onSuccess={(res) => {`
          `// handle response here`
        `}}`
        `ref={paystackWebViewRef}`
      `/>`

        `<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> paystackWebViewRef.current.startTransaction()}>`
          `<Text>Pay Now</Text>`
        `<TouchableOpacity/>`
      `</View>`
 ` );`
`}`
```

Comment: If you have any better and latest approach to Paystack integration in React Native, I will appreaciate it.

Comment: Can you share the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

your code are strings...  remove the quotes (``) at the start and end of each line